# How to insert multiple images into shiny after click of a button?

Tags: r, shiny

I created a shiny app which has two buttons as you can see in the following screenshot. I want to display 8 images which I have in [this folder](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F1vJw9neayy5esZCIO3VjcvT9woSjVzK/view?usp=sharing) in the shiny app after I click the "Show Images" button. I tried using renderImages but couldn't get it to work.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
ui.R

fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("For Fun!!"),
  hr(),
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("update", "Print Text"),
      hr(),
      actionButton("test", "Show Images")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("plot"),
      uiOutput("images")
    )
  )
)

server.r 

server <- function(input, output) {

  randomVals <- eventReactive(input$update, {
   myString="Hello!"
   myString
  })


  output$plot <- renderPrint({
    myString=randomVals()
    print(myString)
  })

}
```

This is what I'm looking for as an output:
Thanks for your time

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this.

```
library(shiny)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$files <- renderTable(input$files)

  files <- reactive({
    files <- input$files
    files$datapath <- gsub("\\\\", "/", files$datapath)
    files
  })


  output$images <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$files)) return(NULL)
    image_output_list <- 
      lapply(1:nrow(files()),
             function(i)
             {
               imagename = paste0("image", i)
               imageOutput(imagename)
             })

    do.call(tagList, image_output_list)
  })

  observe({
    if(is.null(input$files)) return(NULL)
    for (i in 1:nrow(files()))
    {
      print(i)
      local({
        my_i <- i
        imagename = paste0("image", my_i)
        print(imagename)
        output[[imagename]] <- 
          renderImage({
            list(src = files()$datapath[my_i],
                 alt = "Image failed to render")
          }, deleteFile = FALSE)
      })
    }
  })

})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = 'files', 
                label = 'Select an Image',
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept=c('image/png', 'image/jpeg'))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('files'),
      uiOutput('images')
    )
  )
))

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```